# Repeated query with same questions but different answers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a website that collects users inputs. We give user question and ask them to select answers. There are several questions. In some question user can only select one answer and in some question user can select multiple answer because of check box facilities.

When I write a sql query I get multiple question listed for multiple answer choice question. Like this.

```
Question                                    User Answer
--------                                    -----------
What color is apple?                           Red
What color is banana?                         Yellow
Days in Weekday?                              Monday    
Days in Weekday?                              Tuesday
Days in Weekday?                              Wednesday
Days in Weekday?                              Thursday
Days in Weekday?                              Friday
Total days in a week?                          7
```

What I want is something like this....

```
Question                                    UserAnswer
--------                                    -----------
What color is apple?                           Red
What color is banana?                         Yellow
Days in Weekday?                              Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
Total days in a week?                          7
```

I tried to use distinct but since these are texts I cannot use distinct... Could anyone give me an easy approach to this?

I use PHP with MySQL. Both Question and UserAnswer is stored in different table but relation is made.

Thank You.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: store the value in variable. and then use them as you want try it your self. if you fail you can post your code here. Thanks

Comment: I tried and got that result with multiple question for the answers. But I need different result which will only display one question for multiple answers ... just like above.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT questions.question_text, GROUP_CONCAT(answer.answer_text SEPARATOR ',')
FROM questions 
    LEFT JOIN answer ON question.id = answer.question_id
GROUP BY question.id
```

Obviously the table/column names will be whatever they are.  And left join ensures you get questions with no answers, which you may or may not want.

[Edit] With your tables, it should be

```
SELECT questions.text, GROUP_CONCAT(answers.text SEPARATOR ',')
FROM questions
    LEFT JOIN UserResponse ON questions.id = UserResponse.question_id
    LEFT JOIN answers on UserResponse.answer_id = answers.id
GROUP BY question.id
```

This will be for all users - presumably in your UserResponse table you have a user id you might add in as a WHERE?

Comment: It is always a good idea to aggregate all your non grouped columns in a select with a group by... You'll get yeld at by MySQL in strict mode if you don't. For this particular example I'd do MIN(questions.question_text)

Comment: Hello- but my tables are structured in a different way. There is a table called questions with fields(id, text) and table called answers with fields(id, text) which is filled up with questions in question table and answers in answer table. And there is another table called UserResponse.Which has table fields such as(id, question_id, answer_id). So when users answers and selects options, in the background the script is passing the number like 1,2,3 etcs for questions and answers to UserResponse(id, question_id, answer_id)...How to fix the above issue in this case.? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT questions, GROUP_CONCAT(User_Answer) as User_Answer
FROM table_name GROUP BY questions
```

Take a look on [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for more information.